# Python dateformat does not match Portugese format locale

Tags: python, datetime, locale

I'm trying to parse Portugese date into datetime. Below is what I'm trying:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_PT.iso88591')
date_format = '%A, %d %B %Y, %H:%M'
date_str = 'sexta-feira, 8 de setembro de 2017, 20:08'
datetime.strptime(date_str, date_format)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'sexta-feira, 8 de setembro de 2017, 20:08' does not 
  match format '%A, %d %B %Y, %H:%M'
```

Also tried below date_str but still getting the same error:

```
date_str = 'sexta-feira, 8 setembro 2017, 20:08'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX date and time format has limited support for different date formats. I suggest you take a look at PyICU:

```
from datetime import datetime
from icu import Locale, DateFormat, ICUtzinfo, TimeZone
locale = Locale('pt_PT')
tz = ICUtzinfo.getInstance('Portugal')
now = datetime.now(tz)
df = DateFormat.createDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.kFull, DateFormat.kFull, locale)
s = df.format(now)
print s
now2 = df.parse(s)
print now2
s2 = df.format(now2)
print s2
```

Output:

```
sexta-feira, 8 de setembro de 2017 às 23:26:20 Hora de verão da Europa Central
1504905980.0
sexta-feira, 8 de setembro de 2017 às 23:26:20 Hora de verão da Europa Central
```

> I'm scraping a website so I need to convert a date string (sexta-feira, 8 de setembro de 2017, 20:08) into datetime so I can save it into database. How would I do that using PyICU?

This would require custom CLDR pattern:

```
df = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyy, HH:mm", locale)
print df.parse('sexta-feira, 8 de setembro de 2017, 20:08')
```

Comment: hmm I'm scraping a website so I need to convert a date string (sexta-feira, 8 de setembro de 2017, 20:08) into datetime so I can save it into database. How would I do that using PyICU?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test the reverse conversion with `strftime` method. For your example it looks like this (and is pretty obvious, why your `strptime` doesn't work):

```
In [1]: import locale

In [2]: from datetime import datetime

In [3]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_PT.ISO-8859-1')
Out[3]: 'pt_PT.ISO-8859-1'

In [4]: date_format = '%A, %d %B %Y, %H:%M'

In [5]: datetime.now().strftime(date_format)
Out[5]: 'S\xe1bado, 09 Setembro 2017, 00:02'
```

Comment: Why is it "pretty obvious"? The only difference I see is the padding zero and capitalization. Unless you mean "Sábado" (Saturday) and "Sexta-feira" (Friday)? His example "sexta-feira, 8 setembro 2017, 20:08" matches your output except by capitalization and leading zero (and a different date).

Comment: By "pretty obvious" I meant that it's easy to track down the real concerns by cross-referencing both conversions. I answered with a method to debug this issue and the example given just illustrated that. But for making it more obvious: `strptime` and `strftime` don't know what 'sexta-feira' is, instead they know just 'sexta'.